# find and save variable in cookie

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to save variable in cookie and then retrieve it, so far i can save just a text and page url and then retrieve it where ever i want.

Could u please help me out with it?for example in this code i want to save $room and $renthome values in cookie.

this is my current code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>New page string name</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> <!-- Resource style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/buy-rent.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = '',
    date = new Date();
    if (days) {
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      expires = '; expires=' + date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + expires + '; path=/';
  }
  /*
  * Read cookie by name.
  * In your case the return value will be a json array with list of pages saved.
  */
  function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + '=',
    allCookies = document.cookie.split(';'),
    i,
    cookie;
    for (i = 0; i < allCookies.length; i += 1) {
      cookie = allCookies[i];
      while (cookie.charAt(0) === ' ') {
        cookie = cookie.substring(1, cookie.length);
      }
      if (cookie.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
        return cookie.substring(nameEQ.length, cookie.length);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  /*
  * Erase cookie with name.
  * You can also erase/delete the cookie with name.
  */
  function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, '', -1);
  }

  var faves = new Array();

  function isAlready(){
    var is = false;
    $.each(faves,function(index,value){
      if(this.url == window.location.href){
        console.log(index);
          faves.splice(index,1);
          is = true;
      }
    });
    return is;
  }

  $(function(){
    var url = window.location.href; // current page url
    $(document.body).on('click','#addTofav',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var pageTitle = $(document).find("title").text();
      if(isAlready()){
      } else {
          var fav = {'title':pageTitle,'url':url};
          faves.push(fav);
      }
      var stringified = JSON.stringify(faves);
      createCookie('favespages', stringified);
      location.reload();
    });


     var myfaves = JSON.parse(readCookie('favespages'));
     if(myfaves){
       faves = myfaves;
     } else {
       faves = new Array();
     }

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addTofav">Add me to fav</a>
  <div class="img">
    <div class="desc">
  <ul id="appendfavs">
   
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
<?php
error_reporting(0);

include("config.php");

$quer= "SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." ";


$query=mysqli_query($connect,$quer)
or die(mysqli_error());
?>

<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):
$idhome= $row['idhome'];
$room=$row['room'];
$renthome=$row['renthome'];
$pricehome=$row['pricehome'];
?>

 <?php endwhile;?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, you should use [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin.

This creates a cookie

```
$.cookie(name, value [, options]);
```

and then retrieve it value

```
$.cookie(name);
```

Comment: thank u for your answering but  think u did not get my question. i am not having problem to define a cookie name or value. to simplify my code i deleted that part. if u notice i want to save a whole other variable in cookie and the retrieve it. like page title which i did it. i edit my code please wake a look at it thank u again

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery Cookie

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

usage: `$.cookie('name', 'value');`

retrieving: `$.cookie('name'); // => "value"`

In order to save complex data in a cookie, do the following:

1) save the whole data in an object. Something like `var cookieData = {};`, and then you can add properites like `cookieData.date = yourDate; cookieData.myUrl=yourUrl;`

2) transfer the object to a sting using `JSON.stringify`

3) save the string in the cookie.

Now, in order to use it again -

1) retrieve the cookie (See the code above)

2) Turn the string back into an object using `JSON.parse`

3) Fetch the data you desire from the object

Comment: thank u for your answering but  think u did not get my question. i am not having problem to define a cookie name or value. to simplify my code i deleted that part. if u notice i want to save a whole other variable in cookie and the retrieve it. like page title which i did it. i edit my code please wake a look at it thank u again

Comment: i have a question, how can i save multiple variable in an object is it like this:
var cookieData = {$idhome,$room,$renthome};

Comment: What parameters would you like to save?

Comment: excuse me i am a little confused.
 could u please add a simple code to your answer

Comment: pk i want to save for example $idhome= $row['idhome']; and
$room=$row['room']; in cookie and then retrieve them

Comment: Tell me the parameters you want to save in the cookie and I'll post the code that you need

Comment: $idhome= $row['idhome']; and $room=$row['room'];  - are PHP data from server side.

Comment: Then you'll need to use PHP setcookie()
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can generate in PHP `<script>` block which will save the variable. Example show saving cookie named `room` by `$room` value.

```
<script>
     createCookie("room", "<?= $row['room'] ?>", 2);
</script>
```

another (and I think better) way is to set the cookie by PHP.

```
<?php setcookie("room", $row['room'], 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); ?>
```

Don't forget that if you want to set cookie by PHP yhou have to do it before send any output. In your case you have to prepare output, set cookie and then send the output.

Comment: hi thank you for your answering i get  the value of variables from database thus  can i change your above question like this

Comment: `<?php setcookie("$row[room]", $room, 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); ?>`

Comment: It is not right, first param is cookie name, second is value. In answer it is updated.